# SwiftUI4.0 NavigationStack(path: $pathList) + CustomNavigationBar How can I manage PathList when doing swipe back?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

When using NavigationStack and CustomNavigationBar together, I don't know how to manage PathList for Swipeback action. Do you know anything?

```
public func navigationController(
     _navigationController: UINavigationController,
     willShow_: UIViewController,
     animated_: Bool
   ) to detect SwipeBack and control the pathList, but if it is already caught in the method, it is dismissed.
```